# unsupported operand type(s) tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

hi I'm new to programming and was making a program that will calculate compound interest but haven't been able to get it to work with tkinter. when  I press the calculate button I get errors and the GUI varible for the answer doesn't update, any help would be great :)  I've tried everything I could find on this

```
    # gui importation
import tkinter as tk

root: tk = tk.Tk()
root.title('Compound Interest')

# entry labels
tk.Label(root, text="Principal").grid(row=0)
tk.Label(root, text="Interest rate pa").grid(row=1)
tk.Label(root, text="Number of years").grid(row=2)
tk.Label(root, text="Compounds per year").grid(row=3)

# entry's
e1 = tk.Entry(root)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2 = tk.Entry(root)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
e3 = tk.Entry(root)
e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
e4 = tk.Entry(root)
e4.grid(row=3, column=1)

amount = tk.IntVar(root)


# sets seta var from entry inputs
def seta():
    principal = (e1.get())
    interest = (e2.get())
    years = (e3.get())
    compound = (e4.get())
    amount.set(float(principal * pow(1 + (interest / compound), compound * years)) - principal)
    root.after(1000, seta)
    print('total amount = %.2f' % amount)


# button trigger seta update
tk.Button(root, text="Calculate", command=seta).grid(row=4, column=1, pady=4)
tk.Label(root, text=amount).grid(row=3, column=2)
root.mainloop()
```

errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\CompoundInterest\main.py", line 32, in seta
    amount.set(float(principal * pow(1 + (interest / compound), compound * years)) - principal)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: `Entry.get()` returns string and you need to convert it to integer or float.

Answer (score 1):

You get values as strings, which needs to be converted to numbers before applying your formula, replace

```
def seta():
    principal = (e1.get())
    interest = (e2.get())
    years = (e3.get())
    compound = (e4.get())
```

using

```
def seta():
    principal = float(e1.get())
    interest = float(e2.get())
    years = float(e3.get())
    compound = float(e4.get())
```

Answer (score 1):

`.get()` function returns the values as a string. You need to convert it to an integer before you calculate. Also, there is no point doing `root.after(2000,seta)`.

```
def seta():
    principal = float(e1.get())
    interest = float(e2.get())
    years = float(e3.get())
    compound = float(e4.get())
    compounds=float(principal * pow(1 + (interest / compound), compound * years) - principal)
```

Here is the full code :

```
import tkinter as tk

root: tk = tk.Tk()
root.title('Compound Interest')

# entry labels
tk.Label(root, text="Principal").grid(row=0)
tk.Label(root, text="Interest rate pa").grid(row=1)
tk.Label(root, text="Number of years").grid(row=2)
tk.Label(root, text="Compounds per year").grid(row=3)

# entry's
e1 = tk.Entry(root)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2 = tk.Entry(root)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
e3 = tk.Entry(root)
e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
e4 = tk.Entry(root)
e4.grid(row=3, column=1)



# sets seta var from entry inputs
def seta():
    principal = float(e1.get())
    interest = float(e2.get())
    years = float(e3.get())
    compound = float(e4.get())
    compounds=principal * pow(1 + (interest / compound), compound * years) - principal
    lb1.config(text=f'Amount: {round(compounds,2)}')
    
   

# button trigger seta update
tk.Button(root, text="Calculate", command=seta).grid(row=4, column=1, pady=4)
lb1=tk.Label(root,text='')
lb1.grid(row=5, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```